# How to choose to set back-end using rewrite-uri to two different logic apps in Azure API Management?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I'm trying to choose between two different logic apps using a when condition:

```
<inbound>
    <set-variable name="CompanyID" value="@((string)context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("CompanyID"))" />
    <set-variable name="AuthKey" value="@((string)context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("AuthKey"))" />
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("CompanyID") == "1" && context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("AuthKey") == "1")">
            <set-method id="apim-generated-policy">GET</set-method>
            <rewrite-uri id="apim-generated-policy" template="/manual/paths/invoke/?api-version=2016-06-01&amp;sp=/triggers/manual/run&amp;sv=1.0&amp;sig={{apibrokerlogicapp_manual-invoke_5d36ff21ed}}" />
            <set-header id="apim-generated-policy" name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("CompanyID") == "2" && context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("AuthKey") == "2")">
            <set-method id="apim-generated-policy">GET</set-method>
            <rewrite-uri id="apim-generated-policy" template="/manual/paths/invoke/?api-version=2016-06-01&amp;sp=/triggers/manual/run&amp;sv=1.0&amp;sig={{apibrokerlogicapp_manual-invoke_5d36ff21ed}}" />
            <set-header id="apim-generated-policy" name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
        </when>
        <otherwise />
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

My two variables "CompanyID" and "AuthKey" decides which logic app to execute, in the case above, both the same logic app will be executed due to this line:

```
<rewrite-uri id="apim-generated-policy" template="/manual/paths/invoke/?api-version=2016-06-01&amp;sp=/triggers/manual/run&amp;sv=1.0&amp;sig={{apibrokerlogicapp_manual-invoke_5d36ff21ed}}"
```

The line above will execute logic app 1, but how to execute logic app 2? Where get I find the following URL in my logic App so I can change this in my expression?

```
/manual/paths/invoke/?api-version=2016-06-01&amp;sp=/triggers/manual/run&amp;sv=1.0&amp;sig={{apibrokerlogicapp_manual-invoke_5d36ff21ed
```

Hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you maintain the policy on your own anyway, you're safe to remove all instances of id="apim-generated-policy"

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the corresponding back-end-services (you find these in the all operations policy of the APIs imported from LogicApps) and check that the query parameters also match correspondingly:

```
<inbound>
    <set-variable name="CompanyID" value="@((string)context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("CompanyID"))" />
    <set-variable name="AuthKey" value="@((string)context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("AuthKey"))" />
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("CompanyID") == "1" && context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("AuthKey") == "1")">
            <set-backend-service backend-id="LogicApp_kw1_kw" />
            <set-method>GET</set-method>
            <rewrite-uri template="/manual/paths/invoke/?api-version=2016-06-01&amp;sp=/triggers/manual/run&amp;sv=1.0&amp;sig={{kw1_manual-invoke_5d680fe2da5ce8c03b53263b}}" />
            <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("CompanyID") == "2" && context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("AuthKey") == "2")">
            <set-backend-service backend-id="LogicApp_kw2_kw" />
            <set-method>GET</set-method>
            <rewrite-uri template="/manual/paths/invoke/?api-version=2016-06-01&amp;sp=/triggers/manual/run&amp;sv=1.0&amp;sig={{kw2_manual-invoke_5d68100a2fe4c33527ceaf4d}}" />
            <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
        </when>
        <otherwise />
    </choose>
</inbound>
```